# How to reference element of navigation property in detail view?

Tags: sapui5

I am trying to get Data from a navigation property to display in my detailview.
[Image shows the definition of the entities in sap gateway](https://i.stack.imgur.com/n76nW.png)

The association is a 1:1 association.

If I use the link to the navigation property directly it gives the proper result:
link:
/sap/opu/odata/namespace/PROJECTBUILDER_SRV/PROJEKTSet('00002403')/TechnicalSpecs
result:

```
<entry xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2005/Atom" xmlns:m="http://schemas.microsoft.com/ado/2007/08/dataservices/metadata" xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/ado/2007/08/dataservices" xml:base="/sap/opu/odata/namespace/PROJECTBUILDER_SRV/">
    <id>/sap/opu/odata/namespace/PROJECTBUILDER_SRV/TECHNICAL_SPECSSet('Test%20Service%202')</id>
    <title type="text">TECHNICAL_SPECSSet('Test%20Service%202')</title>
    <updated>2021-12-02T13:06:38Z</updated>
    <category term="PROJECTBUILDER_SRV.TECHNICAL_SPECS" scheme="http://schemas.microsoft.com/ado/2007/08/dataservices/scheme"/>
    <link href="TECHNICAL_SPECSSet('Test%20Service%202')" rel="self" title="TECHNICAL_SPECS"/>
    <content type="application/xml">
    <m:properties>
        <d:Equipment>Test Service 2</d:Equipment>
        <d:Pspnr>00002403</d:Pspnr>
        <d:Turbine>TurbineName</d:Turbine>
        <d:NominalPowerE>2,5 MW</d:NominalPowerE>
        <d:NominalPowerM>4 MW</d:NominalPowerM>
        <d:RotorDiameter>80 M</d:RotorDiameter>
        <d:RotorSpeed>5,92/12 RPM</d:RotorSpeed>
        <d:GridFrequency>50 HZ</d:GridFrequency>
        <d:GeneratorSpeed>379 RPM</d:GeneratorSpeed>
        <d:GearboxRatio>50,6</d:GearboxRatio>
        <d:NominalTorque>4700 KNM</d:NominalTorque>
        <d:MaxTorque>9800 KNM</d:MaxTorque>
    </m:properties>
    </content>
</entry>
```

But in ui5 view the fields stay empty (the getEntity-Method isn't called either) - so I must be referencing it in a wrong way:
The view I am in uses a route to PROJEKTSet and inside this view I am trying to say:

```
<m:Input value="{/TechnicalSpecs>/Equipment}" editable="false" visible="true" id="DetailEquipment"/>
```

What is the correct way to get the value "Equipment" of Entity TechnicalSpecs, which has an association with PROJEKT?

Comment: Can you show how the entity is bound to your view or input field? The syntax with the larger than sign `>` is reserved for models, which is not correct here. It'll be something like `TechnicalSpecs/Equipment` or `/TechnicalSpecs/Equipment` depending on your bindings, or `ModelFromManifest>/Technical...` in case you named the model

Comment: `"routes": [{"pattern": "", "name": "master", "target": "master" }, 
{"pattern": "PROJEKTSet/{objectId}", "name": "object", "target": ["master", "object"] }],
"targets": { 
"master": { "viewName": "Master", "viewLevel": 1, "viewId": "master" },
"object": { "viewName": "Detail", "viewId": "detail", "viewLevel": 1, "controlAggregation": "midColumnPages" }`
So in the Input field I am trying to call `PROJEKTSet/{objectId}/TechnicalSpecs/Equipment` @Jorg